# What's the deal with all these Chuck montages?

Tags: community

[Planet Ubuntu](http://planet.ubuntu.com/) is full of hilarious Chuck montages. Here two examples:

[image: Chuck with Steve Balmer jumping around.]

[image: More Chuckness.]

Why is that? How did Chuck become an Ubuntu meme?

*Note: This question is not meant to be a Chuck montage collection. It is a real question!*

Comment: I was going to say this is a little off topic or maybe should go on the meta site but after checking the site out... and other related site, I mean COME ON! the guy is everywhere. Some kind of Chuck 2.0 virus. Who is Chuck and why is he injecting himself in every image.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to Movember? ![chuckvember](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ehksF.jpg)

Comment: wtf is chuck???

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I highly doubt it's actually "Chuck" who is doing this :)

Comment: Memes indicate who in particular and how many people in general have poor creativity and sense of humor.

Comment: Where in the World is Chuck today?

Answer (score 10):

Chuck is Chuck Short - [~zulcss](https://launchpad.net/~zulcss) - I believe he has become famous due to his love of WHAM, Boy George and the Village People and is leveraging his fame to teach people the Ubuntu Dance (as seen below).

[image: Chuck Mob]

Answer (score 2):

This (community-wiki) answer will serve as a reference for all "Chuck" pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]